# Docker How to split USB devices between docker images?

Tags: docker

If I will try to map the whole `/dev` directory, all will work but one USB device that should not be in this image will appear there and I need to exclude it.

When I try to split devices between docker images, something like this:

```bash
sudo docker run -v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro -e TZ=Europe/Kiev --cgroup-parent -dt --rm -v /home/user/project:/root/project --privileged --shm-size=0 --group-add root -p 8080:8080/tcp -p 8081:8081/tcp --device=/dev/bus/usb/001/110 --device=/dev/bus/usb/001/109 --device=/dev/bus/usb/001/108 --device=/dev/bus/usb/001/107 --device=/dev/bus/usb/001/106 image/name
```

I got the error that not available memory: `OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device`

It happens, because I did not map additional disk space that is mounted under `/dev` folder (like `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sda1` and etc.)

Is there a way to exclude not needed USB device and at the same time mount memory ? For example, is it possible to do `--device=^*****` patttern to exclude device and mount completely the whole `/dev` folder